# Name of a family of Coxeter groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, coxeter-groups

From the following image I know that the first of group is the symmetric group of rank $n$ and the second is known as the [Hyperoctahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group).

[image]

I want to know if someone knows **the name** of the third family of groups. Wikipedia does not have links to see anything about this groups. But I'm pretty sure that it's stored in the web just with the original name.

Answer (score 3):

I've worked extensively with these groups and mostly I just refer to them by a symbol or casually say "type D." I've used "demihyperoctahedral group" before, and I believe I saw it in the literature, but I don't recall where. I don't think anyone will tell you you're wrong if you use that name.

Comment: I want to study a little about this groups. For example: the number of conjugaccy classes, if there exist a normal subgroup of index 2.

Comment: @Metaknight well, the group is a subgroup of the hyperoctahedral group of index 2, and there's a nice combinatorial description of the group. I don't know much about the conjugacy classes though. You could read the 8th chapter of Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups by Bjorner and Brenti, or you may be able to find a free reference looking up "even signed permutations" (I originally learned from a free reference I think but I don't remember which).